# How do I dynamically set the height for the MuiDateCalendar-viewTransition container in MUI DateCalendar component?

Tags: css, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I have implemented the [DateCalendar](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-calendar/) MUI component in my application. Based on this [forum](https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/1192), it seems as though the built-in height of the Date Calendar accounts for 6 weeks in a month, and when a month has less than 6 weeks the height does not shrink to fit the contents, but rather it shows white-space.

I do not want there to be any whitespace. I believe it is the .MuiPickersSlideTransition-root element that I want to change, but I am not 100% sure.

I have tried to adjust the min-height for the .MuiPickersSlideTransition-root component, but this does not allow for the height to expand past the min-height.

I have also tried to implement the solution presented in the github forum mentioned above, and that also did not work.